# Can't properly pass DateTime value through JSON to ASP.NET CRUD action

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net, sql-server

I have this CRUD action on the backend, I mainly use Swagger to check it and it works just fine, it just asks for a single JSON pair:

```
{
  "dateAssigned": "2024-01-17T12:41:10.864Z"
}
```

I really don't get the problem here as it is just a simple voucher system; the user just copy-pastes the UUID, the `ExamVoucher` table gets updated as I want, and then error (it is supposed to write some other data and a date to the other table called `Exams`).

Here is the picture of how it looks on Swagger:

[image: Swagger CRUD action]

So the front-end part is this:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker'; // make sure to install react-datepicker
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'; // Default styling
import AuthContext from '../../AuthContext'; // Adjust path as needed
import { format } from 'date-fns';

const RedeemVoucher = () => {
const [voucherCode, setVoucherCode] = useState('');
const [examDate, setExamDate] = useState(new Date());
const { token } = useContext(AuthContext);

const handleRedeem = async () => {
    try {
        const formattedDate = examDate.toISOString();
        const response = await fetch(`https://localhost:5888/api/ExamVouchers/RedeemVoucher/${voucherCode}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ redeemVoucherDto: { dateAssigned: formattedDate } }) // Adjusted structure
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            const errorText = await response.text();
            console.error('Response Status:', response.status, 'Response Text:', errorText);
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }

        alert('Voucher redeemed successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error redeeming voucher:', error);
        alert('Error redeeming voucher: ' + error.message);
    }
};



return (
    <div className="container">
        <h2>Redeem Voucher</h2>
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter Voucher Code"
                value={voucherCode}
                onChange={(e) => setVoucherCode(e.target.value)}
            />
        </div>
        <div>
            <DatePicker
                selected={examDate}
                onChange={(date) => { console.log(date);setExamDate(date)}}
                showTimeSelect
                //dateFormat="Pp"
            />
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleRedeem} className="btn btn-primary">
                Redeem
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
);
};

export default RedeemVoucher;
```

and the backend API is this:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPut("RedeemVoucher/{voucherCode}")]
    public IActionResult RedeemVoucher(Guid voucherCode, [FromBody] RedeemVoucherDto redeemVoucherDto)
    {
        var userIdClaim = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "id");
        if (userIdClaim == null)
        {
            return Unauthorized("User ID is missing.");
        }
        var userId = int.Parse(userIdClaim.Value);
        var candidate = _context.Candidates.FirstOrDefault(c => c.UserId == userId);

        if (candidate == null)
        {
            return NotFound("Candidate not found.");
        }
        var voucher = _context.ExamVouchers.FirstOrDefault(v => v.VoucherCode == voucherCode);



        if (voucher == null || voucher.IsUsed)
        {

            return Unauthorized("Voucher not found or already used.");
        }

        voucher.CandidateId = candidate.CandidateId;
        voucher.IsUsed = true;
        _context.SaveChanges();

        Exam exam = new Exam
        {
            CandidateId = candidate.CandidateId,
            VoucherId = voucher.VoucherId,
            DateAssigned =  redeemVoucherDto.DateAssigned,
            CertificateId = voucher.CertificateId
        };

        _context.Exams.Add(exam);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Ok("Voucher redeemed and exam scheduled.");
    }
```

I tried using many date formats, my database is made of this:

```
CREATE TABLE Exam (
    ExamID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    CandidateID INT,
    VoucherID INT, 
    DateAssigned DATETIME,
    CertificateID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (CandidateID) REFERENCES Candidates(CandidateID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CertificateID) REFERENCES Certificate(CertificateID),
    FOREIGN KEY (VoucherID) REFERENCES ExamVoucher(VoucherID),
);
```

> SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

If I `Console.Writeline` I can see that the date that the back-end reads is actually "1/1/0001 12:00".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the body with a nested object. Remove the outer part `redeemVoucherDto`.

```
const response = await fetch(`https://localhost:5888/api/ExamVouchers/RedeemVoucher/${voucherCode}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ dateAssigned: formattedDate })
});
```

Comment: I swear... No more all-nighters for me... It was THAT stupid of a mistake. I know the rules are against "Thanks" and such on the comments area but man you saved my life.